# Android webView.loadUrl can contain jquery function

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview

we can call javascript function in loadUrl as below.

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { var x=3+4;alert(3);})()");
```

Is it possible to add jquery function in loadUrl i.e $.post in loadUrl method of Webview.
    if yes then help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is javascript. So you can :

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:$('.navbar').css('display', 'none');");
```

Also don't forget to enable javascript on the webview :

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```